# How can I make the GCC error messages more readable (e.g., with color)?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, gcc, clang

I am compiling C++ code with GCC (usually via Make) on Linux. I am also often working with heavily templatized code (OpenFOAM). Whenever I am trying to understand compilation errors, I am having a hard time even finding out where the error message is in the wall of text, as well as key information, such as which line of my code (the object file I am building) triggered the error.

Is there any way to enable color or generally syntax highlighting in GCC? If not, is there any other way people use to address this problem, even on the shell level?

I assume that the same problem also applies in LLVM (if not, let me know).

(the question naturally extends also to runtime errors/call stacks of C++ programs)

Comment: It is already enabled. Use the last stable version of gcc/clang and you should see it.

Comment: It looks like this is specific to OpenFOAM. I opened an [issue](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/issues/2661). Passing `-fdiagnostics-color=always` to the compiler for the OpenFOAM-related code I was building helped.